# Change fillcolor based on colorbar for ScatterPolar

Tags: python, plotly

I am creating a ScatterPolar plot with three numbers attached and I have a fourth number that I want to determine the fillcolor. Where the fourth number can fall between 0 and 1 and a colorbar shows the colorscale for that range.

I am using plotly 3.1.1 and python version 3.6.3.

I cannot figure out how to get colorbar to influence the color of fillcolor. Here is what I have so far:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
num_1 = 0.3
num_2 = 0.6
num_3 = 0.9
num_4 = 0.5

# Create radar plot
data = [go.Scatterpolar(
    r = [num_1, num_2, num_3],
    theta = ['number_1', 'number_2', 'number_3'],
    fill = 'toself',
    fillcolor = 'red', # I want this to change based on value of num_4
    opacity = 0.5,
    marker = dict(
        cmin = 0,
        cmax = 1,
        colorbar = dict(title='title'),
        colorscale = 'Viridis'
    ),
    mode = 'markers'
)]

# Create layout
layout = go.Layout(
    polar = dict(
        radialaxis = dict(visible = True, range = [0, 1])
    ),
    showlegend = False
)

# Plot data (using Jupyter notebook)
fig = go.FigureWidget(data=data, layout=layout)
fig
```

Here is the output for the image, however I want the red color to change based on the value of `num_4`:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib`'s colormaps to get rgba values, visualization libraries often have the same standard colormaps.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from matplotlib import cm

num_1 = 0.3
num_2 = 0.6
num_3 = 0.9
num_4 = 0.5

cmap = cm.get_cmap('Viridis')

# Create radar plot
data = [go.Scatterpolar(
    r = [num_1, num_2, num_3],
    theta = ['number_1', 'number_2', 'number_3'],
    fill = 'toself',
    fillcolor = 'rgba' + str(cmap(num_4))
    opacity = 0.5,
    marker = dict(
        cmin = 0,
        cmax = 1,
        colorbar = dict(title='title'),
        colorscale = 'Viridis'
    ),
    mode = 'markers'
)]

# Create layout
layout = go.Layout(
    polar = dict(
        radialaxis = dict(visible = True, range = [0, 1])
    ),
    showlegend = False
)

# Plot data (using Jupyter notebook)
fig = go.FigureWidget(data=data, layout=layout)
fig
```